# Reading RVT file

Tags: c#, text, revit

When I open any .RVT file in notepad, I can search and find 'R E V I T', I tried everything to find the same text in C#, but no success to encode the .RVT file, any solution?

Comment: What did you try? Can you add the code you already write even if it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

You may have more luck reading the text strings in Unicode encoding. However, that will not help you decrypt very much. To achieve more, you can read the RVT file as a structured OLE storage container. Several different approaches are discussed in various articles by [The Building Coder](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com):

- [Open Revit OLE Storage](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/06/open-revit-ole-storage.html)
- [Basic File Info and RVT File Version](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2013/01/basic-file-info-and-rvt-file-version.html)
- [Custom File Properties](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2015/09/lunar-eclipse-and-custom-file-properties.html#3)
- [Reading an RVT File without Revit](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/02/reading-an-rvt-file-without-revit.html)
- [Determining RVT File Version Using Python](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/06/determining-rvt-file-version-using-python.html)
- [Retrieve RVT Preview Thumbnail Image with Python](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/06/accessing-bim360-cloud-links-thumbnail-and-dynamo.html#3)